# Wrong axes in PSTricks figure using \psaxes

Tags: pstricks, pst-plot

Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks-add}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \centering
  \begin{pspicture}(-0.8,-0.8)(6.3,6.3)
    \psaxes[
      dx = 1.25,
      Dx = 1.25,
      dy = 0.5,
      Dy = 0.5,
      xLabels = {,\frac{U_{0}}{2},\frac{U_{1}}{2},\frac{U_{2}}{2},\frac{U_{3}}{2}},
      yLabels = {,\frac{U_{0}}{5},\frac{U_{1}}{5},\frac{U_{2}}{5},\frac{U_{3}}{5}}
    ]{->}(0,0)(-0.2,-0.2)(5.5,5.5)[$X$,0][$Y$,90]
  \end{pspicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

I would like to fix the following issues:

1. Remove the three `.2`.
2. Put the labels next to the ticks.

P.S. I thought I knew how to do this but I can't make it work now.

Comment: Seems to me like it is a bug.

Comment: using `(0,0)(5.5,5.5)[$X$,0][$Y$,90]` instead of `(0,0)(-0.2,-0.2)(5.5,5.5)[$X$,0][$Y$,90]` gets rid of the extra `.2`. not sure about the `xLabels` issue yet

Answer (score 4, accepted):

please provide *minimal* examples. It is not important that the object is inside an floating environment.

Try the pst-plot.tex from http://texnik.dante.de/tex/generic/pst-plot/

with

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.8,-0.8)(6.3,6.3)
    \psaxes[
      Dx = 1.25,
      Dy = 0.5,
      xLabels = {,\frac{U_{0}}{2},\frac{U_{1}}{2},\frac{U_{2}}{2},\frac{U_{3}}{2}},
      yLabels = {,\frac{U_{0}}{5},\frac{U_{1}}{5},\frac{U_{2}}{5},\frac{U_{3}}{5}}
    ]{->}(5.5,5.5)[$X$,0][$Y$,90]
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

An axis specification with `(x,y)(x,y)(x,y)` makes no sense here